# Append output of one command to the output of another in a single command

Tags: bash, unix, stdout, pipe

Is there a way to append the stdout output of one command to another's and pipe the combined output to another command? I used to use the following approach(taking `ack-grep` as an example)

```
# List all python, js files in different directories
ack-grep -f --py apps/ > temp
ack-grep -f --js -f media/js >> temp
cat temp | xargs somecommand
```

Is there a way to do this in a single command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run the two `ack-grep` commands as a compound command; then pipe the results of the compund command. The first compound command defined in `man bash` is the parentheses:

```
   (list) list is executed in a subshell environment (see  COMMAND  EXECU-
              TION  ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin com-
              mands that affect the  shell's  environment  do  not  remain  in
              effect  after  the  command completes.  The return status is the
              exit status of list.
```

So:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$echo one > one.txt
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$echo two > two.txt
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$(cat one.txt; cat two.txt) | xargs echo
one two
```

You can use curly braces to similar effect, but curly braces have a few syntactical differences (they're more finicky about needing spaces between the brace and other words, for instance). The biggest difference is that the commands inside braces are run in the *current* shell environment, so they can impact on your environment. For instance:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$HELLO=world; (HELLO=MyFriend); echo $HELLO
world
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$HELLO=world; { HELLO=MyFriend; }; echo $HELLO
MyFriend
```

If you want to get really fancy you can define a function and execute that:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$myfunc () (
> cat one.txt
> cat two.txt
> )
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$myfunc | xargs echo
one two
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$
```

Comment: +1: but `{ ... } | somecommand` is run in a sub-shell and doesn't affect the parent shell.  Demo: `X=PQR; echo $X; { X=ABC; echo $X; } | cat; echo $X` (with output PQR, ABC, PQR on three lines).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler To directly quote `man bash`, the commands inside the braces are `simply executed in the current shell environment`; whereas the commands inside parentheses are `executed in a subshell environment`.

Comment: On the other hand, each element of a pipeline runs in its own subshell. I *think* that's what's causing the behaviour you're seeing here.

Comment: I don't understand what's happening here, so I've posted it as a seperate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109362/bash-subshell-pipelines-which-parts-are-executing-in-subshells

Comment: And I do understand now; both sides of a pipeline are executed in subshells. In this case, that means that `{ .. }` pops into a subshell, while `cat` is in another subshell. This is the *pipeline* creating the subshell, not the braces.

Comment: Yes, it is the pipeline that is poking the activity into a sub-shell, not the braced construct.  But once you have a sub-shell, then the activity in the sub-shell can't affect the parent shell.  This is why you have to be careful with loops that count something from a pipe; in fact, the brace notation can be helpful then to contain the loop and the post-loop processing.

Comment: But the output has it's quotes stripped by xargs!  Instead try using the delimiter options of xargs to only squash and break on the newline '\n' character.  `xargs -d'\n' echo`
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38148/why-does-xargs-strip-quotes-from-input#answer-408983

Answer (score 2):

Group the two commands in curly braces and pipe them:

```
{ ack-grep -f --py apps/; ack-grep -f --js -f media/js; } | xargs somecommand
```

This way you omit the creation of any files.

Comment: This is the way I'd do it.  Just beware that the semi-colon before the close brace is not there for decoration!  You can also use parentheses to enclose the commands in a sub-shell; the semi-colon would not be needed before the close parenthesis.  Yes, there's a reason why.  No; it isn't particularly easy to explain.

Comment: The difference in using braces as in `{ cmd1; cmd2; } | cmd3`, is that it's done in the main shell along with being able to use all the variables defined therin. The other option would be to use parentheses `( cmd1; cmd2; ) | cmd3` which will run separate shell process. And according to [David the H.](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/bash-concatenating-the-output-of-multiple-commands-without-using-temp-files-934604/#post4627698) there is a performance difference too.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
ack-grep -f --py apps/ > temp && ack-grep -f --js -f media/js >> temp && cat temp | xargs somecommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `find`. According to the `ack-grep` man page those options just look for .py and .js files

```
find apps/ media/js -type f -name "*.py" -o -name "*.js" -exec somecommand {} +
```

The `+` option to `-exec` makes it work just like `xargs` but with the benefit that it doesn't die a horrible death if you have files with spaces or newlines or other nasties in their name.