# Bash subshell/pipelines - which parts are executing in subshells?

Tags: bash

In a [comment on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108181/append-output-of-one-command-to-the-output-of-another-in-a-single-command/9108410#comment11442552_9108410), @JonathanLeffler stated that:

> { ... } | somecommand is run in a sub-shell and doesn't affect the
>   parent shell. Demo:
>
> ```
> X=PQR; echo $X; { X=ABC; echo $X; } | cat; echo $X
> ```
>
> (with output PQR, ABC, PQR on three lines)

and indeed:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$X=PQR; echo $X; { X=ABC; echo $X; } | cat; echo $X
PQR
ABC
PQR
```

However, `man bash` says that `{ .. }` does not execute in a subshell:

```
   { list; }
          list  is  simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be 
          terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known as a group command.
```

So what's going on here? Is `man bash` wrong? I know that each part of a pipeline executes in a subshell; but I don't see how that causes the observed behaviour. For instance:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$X=PQR; echo $X | sed;  X=ABC; echo $X | sed; echo $X
PQR
ABC
ABC
```

Edited to add:

A few people have suggested using `echo $$` to show that things are (or are not) parts of a subshell. This is not at all useful, as the `$$` gets expanded during the parameter expansion stage, which happens long before any commands are executed.

As an example:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$echo 1$$; ps; ( echo 2$$; ps ); echo 3$$; ps
11194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.22 -bash
21194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.22 -bash
 7894 ttys000    0:00.00 -bash
31194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.22 -bash
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$
```

You can see that the second invocation of `ps` happened inside a subshell, with pid `7894`; but `echo 2$$` still shows the value that bash substituted in the variable expansion phase, before it spawned the subshell

For contrast, and demonstrating that `{ .. }` does *not* spawn a subshell:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$echo 1$$; ps; { echo 2$$; ps; }; echo 3$$; ps
11194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.22 -bash
21194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.22 -bash
31194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.23 -bash
```

Just to prove that @nos is correct, add a pipeline to the above:

```
james@bodacious-wired:tmp$echo 1$$; ps; { echo 2$$; ps; } | sed ; echo 3$$; ps
11194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.25 -bash
21194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.25 -bash
 7945 ttys000    0:00.00 -bash
 7946 ttys000    0:00.00 sed
31194
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1194 ttys000    0:00.25 -bash
```

As expected, the shell spawns two subshells, one for each side of the pipeline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each side of a pipeline becomes a subshell at least.

```
X=PQR; echo $X; { X=ABC; echo $X; } | cat; echo $X
```

will make a subshell/process of , atleast `{ X=ABC; echo $X; }` and `cat`.

"Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)." , from man bash

If you instead do this

```
X=PQR; echo $X; { X=ABC; echo $X; } ; echo $X
```

You'll see afterwards that `echo $X` shows ABC.

There's other ways that commands are executed in subshells too, e.g. if you background a subcommand: `{ X=SUB ; sleep 1; } &` , that group will run in a subshell, whereas just `{ X=SUB ; sleep 1; }` will not.

If you want to group commands that always execute in a subshell, use parenthesis, `(X=ABC ; echo $X)` instead of braces.

Comment: I think we have a winner. It's not `{ .. }` that's creating the subshell, it's the pipeline. I practically came right out and said that right at the start.

Comment: You need a space after the `{`, at least in my version of `bash`.

Comment: $(cmd args) construct also create a subshell: `echo $(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the braces are executed in a new subshell, **but only if piped**. The first command is with `cat`, the second without:

```
xxx@yyy:~$ ps; X=PQR; echo $X; { ps; X=ABC; echo $X; } | cat; ps; echo $X
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6768 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
13158 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
PQR
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6768 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
13159 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
13160 pts/7    00:00:00 cat
13161 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
ABC
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6768 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
13162 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
PQR
xxx@yyy:~$ ps; X=PQR; echo $X; { ps; X=ABC; echo $X; }; ps; echo $X
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6768 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
13239 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
PQR
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6768 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
13240 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
ABC
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 6768 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
13245 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
ABC
```

In this case `6768` is the PID of the terminal shell, and `13159` is the PID of the subshell started for the braces.

It seems that `{}` are executed in a subshell if (and only if) piped.

Comment: The pipe creates the subshell, not the braces.

Comment: <pedantism>No, it's not the pipe, it's the braces in connection with the pipe. Check the output of `ps` vs. `ps | cat` vs. `{ ps; } | cat`.</pedantism>.

Comment: Braces never invoke a subshell! Only pipes will do this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127334/bash-subshell-creation-with-curly-braces