# How to echoing data from WHOIS records with grep (redirecting standard output into a variable)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, stdout

I have this bash script:

How I can call it the `grep`'s output in the if else statement? If I suppress the output of the `grep` command with `-q`, also will work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DOMAINS=( '.com' '.biz' )

while read input; do
  for (( i=0;i<${#DOMAINS[@]};i++)); do
  jwhois --force-lookup --disable-cache --no-redirect -c jwhois.conf "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}" | MATCH="$(grep -oPa '^.*\b(clientTransferProhibited)\b.*$')"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}\tregistered\t" $(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S) "\t" "$MATCH" |& tee --append output/registered.txt
  else
    echo -e "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}\tavailable\t" $(date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S) "\t" "$MATCH" |& tee --append output/available.txt
  fi
  done
done < "$1"
```

So `MATCH="$(grep -oPa '^.*\b(clientTransferProhibited)` used by `"$MATCH"` in the if else statement not outputting anything, but if I just use `grep -oPa '^.*\b(clientTransferProhibited)`, it's printing the line without problem. The reason why I want to use as a variable, because I want to put in specific places in the if else statements.

Actual output:

```
$ domain1.com       available       15/11/16_14:13:05
$ domain1.biz       available       15/11/16_14:13:05
$ domain2.com        registered      15/11/16_14:13:05
$ domain2.biz        registered      15/11/16_14:13:05
```

Output that I want:

```
$ domain1.com       available       15/11/16_14:13:05
$ domain1.biz       available       15/11/16_14:13:05
$ domain2.com        registered      15/11/16_14:13:05       Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
$ domain2.biz        registered      15/11/16_14:13:05       Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the result of this line is what you want stored in a variable...

```
  jwhois --force-lookup --disable-cache --no-redirect -c jwhois.conf "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}" | grep -oPa '^.*\b(clientTransferProhibited)\b.*$'
```

In that case, you want to evaluate that line and set the entire thing to your desired variable. The type of assignment you attempt in the middle of a pipeline will not be valid.

```
  MATCH=$(jwhois --force-lookup --disable-cache --no-redirect -c jwhois.conf "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}" | grep -oPa '^.*\b(clientTransferProhibited)\b.*$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different MATCH variables, because pipes execute subshells:

[Bash subshell/pipelines - which parts are executing in subshells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109362/bash-subshell-pipelines-which-parts-are-executing-in-subshells)

Try it this way instead:

```
MATCH="$(jwhois --force-lookup --disable-cache --no-redirect -c jwhois.conf "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}" | grep -oPa '^.*\b(clientTransferProhibited)\b.*$')"
```